# Strange result with readline/writeline

Tags: c#, parsing, streamreader, streamwriter

Hello all you geniuses!

I have tried to create a code that reads a txt-file and takes every line starting with the word "PART" in that file and puts it in a new file.

Somehow the outputfile is missing every second line from the original file.
This is my code:

```
{
    string line ="";
    string Starttext = "PART";
    using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\tsnm2171\Desktop\processed\LABB\ORIGINAL.txt"))          
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\tsnm2171\Desktop\processed\LABB\OUTPUT.txt"))


        while (reader.ReadLine() != null)                   

        {   line = reader.ReadLine();

            if (line.StartsWith(Starttext))
                {
                    //writes/starts a new line beginning with PART

                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                }
                else 

                {
                    //appends info to same line (beginning with a space)
                    writer.Write(" " + line);
                }                       
        }
}
```

The original file looks like this:

```
KABEL           RXF 4x25
PART        01      1   1       
PART        02      2   2       
PART        03      3   3       
PART        04      4   4       
PART        SH      GND GND     
KABEL           RXF 4x35    0000000456  Cable RXF 4x35
PART        01  1   5   5       
PART        02  1   6   6       
PART        03  1   7   7       
PART        04  1   8   8       
PART        SH  1   GND GND     
KABEL           RXF 4x35    0000000456  Cable RXF 4x35
PART        01  1   9   9       
PART        02  1   10  10      
PART        03  1   11  11      
PART        04  1   12  12      
PART        SH  1   GND GND
```

But the output file is missing the lines "Part 02" and "Part 04" as below:

```
PART        01      1   1       
PART        03      3   3       
PART        SH      GND GND     
PART        01  1   5   5       
PART        03  1   7   7       
PART        SH  1   GND GND     
PART        01  1   9   9       
PART        03  1   11  11      
PART        SH  1   GND GND
```

Why?

Comment: You're calling `ReadLine` twice for every `WriteLine` call. You almost certainly want `while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)` and remove the subsequent call.

Comment: I will try that. 
Does ReadLine always read the next line evertime it is called?
Can I somehow call for the value in the line before... like readline(-1) or something like that to read the line before?

Comment: "Does ReadLine always read the next line evertime it is called?" Well yes - that's what it's meant to do. And no, you can't ask it to just remember... if you want to retain the result of the previous call, you need to do so yourself.

Comment: Didnt work the way I wanted.
The result was that every line starting with the word KABEL also was copied to the output file but with a blankspace infront of the line.
Also the first line of every bunch of PART was appended directly to the KABEL-line.
Hmmm... Any more ideas?

Comment: Now would be a good time to use the debugger, basically. (But note that sometimes you're calling `Write` and sometimes you're calling `WriteLine`. I strongly suspect that's relevant.)

Comment: Haha... found that now. Thanks for the hint. :-)

Answer (score 4):

`reader.ReadLine()` actually reads a line from the file and move the cursor to next line.

You have called `reader.ReadLine()` twice in your `while` loop

the correct way is

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
{
   // Do your work
}
```